# Zend framework 2: How to set order of <script> tag output in prependFile()

Tags: zend-framework

I'm including my javascript files in my layout using the prependFile() method that is available. However I get an error because the jquery file loads AFTER the bootstrap file. I thought if I change the order these paths are chained in the following it would work:

```
<?php echo $this->headScript()
    ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/jquery.min.js')
    ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js');
?>
```

..but I still get the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

How do I insist upon the order, surely it allows this by some other means if it's not down to the order in which they are chained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `offsetSet()` method, e.g.:

```
<?php echo $this->headScript()
    ->offsetSetFile(50, $this->basePath() . '/js/jquery.min.js')
    ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js');
?>
```

So that in this case jquery will be loaded after bootstrap etc.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So I should do this for bootstrap as I want jQuery to appear first. By the way, is it not odd that prependFile would just put things in random(?) order? Otherwise prependFile seems a little risky to use. Having js files in the correct order is usually quite important and I'd expect that the framework would do this automatically with even the basic method to prepend/include a file.

Comment: Actually `offsetSetFile()` puts a file in particular place, so that you can manipulate it in different places as well; `appendFile() ` appends using the next index - this is what you might want as well, whereas `prependFile()` puts a file to the top - to make sure it's loading first. So in your case, you add `jquery.min.js` to the top of scripts section and then you do the same with `bootstrap.min.js`, which once again puts it to the top ;)